# Como inserir mais de um dado do mesmo tipo, em uma lista em C?

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Quando crio a lista tenho que cadastrar um aluno no nó da lista Vinculo, é possível depois eu inserir outro aluno no mesmo nó, sem sobrescrever o anterior?

```
typedef struct aluno
{
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
    int telefone;
    struct aluno *proximo;
}Aluno;


typedef struct vinculo
{
    float valorMensal;
    Aluno *vinculadoAluno;
    struct vinculo *proximo;
}Vinculo;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Quando crio a lista tenho que cadastrar um aluno no nó da lista Vinculo, é possível depois eu inserir outro aluno no mesmo nó, sem sobrescrever o anterior?

Não, não é possível.

Está talvez confundindo os conceitos, e o modo como declarou a lista não ajuda: uma lista encadeada é de nós --- "*nodes*" --- e não de alunos ou livros ou carros. E cada nó contém ou aponta (seu caso) para um dado, que no seu caso é `struct aluno*`

Considere algo assim e vai ficar mais fácil de entender:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int   matricula;
    char  nome[50];
    int   telefone;
    float valorMensal;
} Aluno;

typedef Aluno Info;

typedef struct vinculo
{
    Info*           info;
    struct vinculo* ant;
    struct vinculo* prox;
} Vinculo;

typedef struct
{
    size_t   tam;
    Vinculo* ini;  // primeiro
    Vinculo* ult;  // ultimo

} Lista;

int    insere(Info*, Lista*);
Lista* cria();
Lista* destroi(Lista*);
```

- A `Lista` é de `Vinculo`.
- Cada `Vinculo` aponta para um dado.
- Nesse caso o dado é `Aluno`.